# Updated an answer to correct my misunderstanding of the question, however

Tags: discussion

I initially misunderstood [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36893517/424129) as a WPF question rather than Windows Universal App. It turns out the answer is different for the two. I updated my answer to be correct, but the WPF answer was correct information, it served as a sort of compare-and-constrast between the two frameworks, and somebody could very easily land on that page from a Google search and actually be looking for the WPF answer.

Should I keep or delete the WPF portion of the answer?

OP figures maybe we should just flag the whole thing as [a duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29041446/424129). I think he's right, but I'm still curious about whether it would be appropriate to keep the WPF material.

Comment: You could ask and answer your own question which is specific to WPF if you feel the answer is helpful. Make sure you follow all of the normal rules for asking and answering though.

Answer (score 4):

No, don't keep an unrelated answer as part of an answer to a specific question. You may ask a new question and answer it yourself so as to put it up on Stack Overflow.

Keep answers specific to the questions.